# janrain widget missing when switching modals

Tags: javascript, janrain

I have a janrain widget that worked fine till a couple of days ago.

There is  a modal that displays the janrain widget on it and clicking on a link on this modal flips to another modal that displays the same janrain widget. For some reason, this widget stopped showing up in firefox and IE after clicking the link on the modal that pops up for the first time. It works in chrome though. In case of firefox and IE, I see the janrainEngageEmbed as empty. Earlier the janrain widget were attached to the janrainEngageEmbed div and will display as long as the janrainEngageEmbed div is visible. I see there was a recent release of janrain js files, not sure if that is causing this issue though.

Any thoughts to debug this issue?

UPDATE: I figured this issue is caused due to the recent changes by janrain with the new version 2013.1_ws_widgets_rc8 they release this january.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling janrain.engage.signin.widget.init() in each click handler. This should make the widget contents reload.

Comment: Thank you juan!! That was a great tip! hats off. Surprised that it used to work before without this init() call.